# worklight app with database not work in real android mobile devices

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I have developed a hybrid application in Ibm worklight using jquerymobile framework. The application accesses database hosted on my own domain using sqladapter. It works fine on Ibm worklight console as well as on AVD. But when I tried to run the application from real android phone, it won't work.I tried to access the database but it does not work in real android device. I saw some solutions that i should connect to worklight server from my device and how is it possible? What steps to be followed further? Help me, i am new to this course.

Comment: Add your adapter's XML to the question.

Comment: <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">       <dataSourceDefinition>
     <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
     <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/system</url>
        <user>root</user>
       <password>root</password> 
    </dataSourceDefinition>
  </connectionPolicy>

Comment: I changed to my host ip address. Whether this solves the problem or still more steps to be done ?

Comment: Save changes and re-deploy the adapter. Also make sure the device is connected to the same network *per my answer below*.

Comment: While running this application in console or AVD  shows this error message and nothng happens                                                      [ERROR   ] FWLSE0012E: ERROR: Could not connect to database. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null,  message from server: "Host 'mannojkumar-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"). [project foreigntradingsystem]

Comment: I wrote "IP address". That is not an IP address.

Comment: I gave ipv4 address of my machine which i got using ipconfig in command prompt but console produce such an error.

Answer (score 0):

When testing in a device you need to make sure the following:

1. The device is connected to *the same* WiFi network as the computer that hosts the Worklight Server
2. The SQL adapter `connectionPolicy` points to the *IP address* of the computer that hosts the Worklight Server.

   Change "localhost" to an IP address:

   ```
   <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
       <dataSourceDefinition>
           <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
           <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</url>
           <user>myUsername</user>
           <password>myPassword</password> 
      </dataSourceDefinition>
   </connectionPolicy>
   ```